# How to display Folders and recent items

Tags: pyqt4, qcombobox, qlistwidget

I have 2 questions in trying to retrieve a set of data from a directory and displays it out into the ListWidget.

As I am a linux user, I set my ListWidget to read my directory from Desktop in which insides contains say 5 folders and 5 misc items (.txt, .py etc)

1. Currently I am trying to make my ListWidget to display just the folders but apparently it does that but it also displays all the items, making it a total of 10 items instead of 5.
   I tried looking up on the net but I am unable to find any info. Can someone help me?
2. Pertaining to Qns 1, I am wondering if it is possible to display the top 3 recent folders in the ListWidget, if a checkbox is being checked?

   ```
   import glob
   import os


   def test(object):
   testList = QListWidget()
   localDir =  os.listdir("/u/ykt/Desktop/test")
   testList.addItems(localDir)
   ```

Comment: Please show the portion of code where you add the items to listWidget

Comment: Added to my main thread, please do have a look. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess that you are expecting that `os.listdir()` will return only the directory names from the given *path*. Actually it returns the file names too. If you want to add only directories to the listWidget, do the following:

   ```
   import os
   osp = os.path
   def test(object):
       testList = QListWidget()
       dirPath = "/u/ykt/Desktop/test"
       localDir = os.listdir(dirPath)
       for dir in lacalDir:
           path = osp.join(dirPath, dir)
           if osp.isdir(path):
               testList.addItem(dir)
   ```

This will add only directories to the listWidget ignoring the files.

1. If you want to get the access time for the files and/or folders, use time following method:

   ```
   import os.path as osp
   accessTime = osp.getatime("path/to/dir") # returns the timestamp
   ```

Get access time for all the directories and one which has the greatest value is the latest accessed directory. This way you can get the latest accessed 3 directories.

Comment: I could not understand the 2nd Q. Can you explain it further? The listWidget now contains 5 directories, how do you want to display 3 recent directories?

Comment: yes there are 5 folders in the directory but I wanted to display the recent 3 folders that has been modified, and hence hiding the other 2.. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try  "QFileDialog" like the following:

```
class MyWidget(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        fileNames = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "list dir", "C:\\",QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
        print fileNames

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

2nd question, you could reference to this: [enter link description here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/mainwindows-recentfiles.html)